# Are Certification Questions Welcome in Programmers?

Tags: discussion

Are Certification questions welcome in Programmers?  I don't mean specific technical questions like how to solve problems in simulation exams, or what a particular technical term means.  I am talking about questions about the certifications and the associated "roadmaps" themselves?

For example, if such questions are allowed, an example of a question I would like to ask if anyone knows if there is a basic C# exam from Microsoft equivalent to the SCJP?  And if not, does anyone know why not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My initial thought on this is no. It seems like that would be best answered by a search engine (in your example, searching for things like "microsoft c# certification" or "c# scjp equivalent") or other questions about roadmaps would be too subjective and localized (the answers depend on you and your career development goals and wouldn't be helpful to everyone, even if they were in the same situation).